# Pseudo-destructor call with template keyword

Tags: c++, templates, destructor, explicit-destructor-call, pseudo-destructor

The following code [does not compile with *clang 5.0.0*](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6L5jjAKAlduq0P90) (compilation flags are `-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors -O0`):

```
struct foo
{
};

int main()
{
    foo f;

    f.~decltype(f)();          // OK
    f.template ~decltype(f)(); // OK

    int i{};

    i.~decltype(i)();          // OK
    i.template ~decltype(i)(); // error: expected unqualified-id
}
```

Is it a way to force the compilation of a pseudo-destructor call with the `template` keyword?

Comment: But why? It's not a template. I'm surprised `f.template ~decltype(f)();` compiles. What's the ultimate problem you are trying to solve, for which you believe adding `template` keyword would be helpful?

Comment: I'm not sure the first one should be accepted either. It's not a template in either case.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - Strictly speaking, the `decltype` one for `foo` is valid. Good to know GCC is buggy too :P

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `template` and `typename` keywords can be used outside templates since C++14.

Comment: @StoryTeller *g++* has a bug here: it can't compile a pseudo-destructor call with the `decltype` keyword.

Comment: @StoryTeller Whaaat. So weird. Thanks :)

Comment: @Constructor, The latest draft has *A name prefixed by the keyword template shall be a template-id or the name shall refer to a class template
or an alias template. [ Note: The keyword template may not be applied to non-template members of class
templates. — end note ]*

Comment: @chris 'Latest draft' means C++14+ or C++17+?

Comment: @Constructor - [Here it is in n4140](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp#names-5). Which is pretty much the same as the official C++14. The change you have in mind is about allowing it to refer to **templates** outside of a template context.

Comment: BTW, @chris, that's an answer. You should post it as one.

Comment: @chris OK. So even `f.template ~decltype(f)();` is illegal, isn't it?

Comment: C++17, specifically, [this PDF](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/draft.pdf), which is unofficial, but convenient. It's in [temp.names]/5, and hasn't changed from N4140 (C++14). Anyway, I don't know why any of these would work, but I'm not that knowledgeable in this area to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, [temp.names]/5 prohibits both of these `.template …` lookups:

> A name prefixed by the keyword template shall be a template-id or the name shall refer to a class template or an alias template. [ Note: The keyword template may not be applied to non-template members of class templates. — end note ]

None of these destructor names are *template-id*s, nor do they refer to class templates or alias templates. However, it's possible that I'm missing something.

Comment: `f.~decltype(f)();` and `i.~decltype(i)();` are still valid pieces of code.

Comment: It is interesting that `f.template ~foo();` gives an error here. So it is an obvious bug in *clang* (explicit destructor call + `decltype` confuse the compiler).

Comment: Oh, yeah, those two are regular pseudo-destructor calls. Not sure why I didn't notice that.

Comment: To be more precise `f.~decltype(f)();` is a regular explicit destructor call.

Comment: That it is. I'm being a bit hasty today.